# are clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml excluded from throttling

Tags: support

These files are requested by the user agent as needed and the programmer has no knowledge or control over these requests.

The abuse potential connected with these files is nil(?)

It seems that it would be a good idea to exclude them from any throttle count.

Comment: Are they actually throttling those files...? Wow.

Comment: @geo - i don't know. that is why i am asking.

Comment: It seems from Jeff's answer that they are :(

Answer (score 2):

Right now this is more of a theoretical problem than an actual one.

If you have a documented case of this being a problem in a production system, with thousands of real world users, do let us know, and we'll follow up.

Comment: jeff, i didn't say there was a problem. when i have an issue, i make it clear that there is a problem and support it with evidence. this is simply a question, which you have not answered.

Comment: @code, you really don't have to sound so hostile all of the time.  It's really intense.  I feel like Jeff implicitly said that those files are indeed throttled too. - "this is more of a theoretical problem than an actual one" (So, there is, in theory, a problem with the files being throttled)

Comment: @jjn - i am not hostile. i asked a specific question which was replied to with an implication, which is not an answer. i am a programmer who is writing code against an ostensibly professional api. when i ask a specific question regarding this api, which we were invited to code against, i appreciate direct and accurate answers and am simply making this clear. the number of times that i have simply played along and keep asking the same question in different ways in order to get an authoritative response have left me weary. that's what i am, tired.

Comment: (@code, to be clear, I don't actually think you are hostile, I just said that you *sound* hostile)  But, I can understand your frustration.